# Book on Algebraic Spaces?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm actually studying "the geometry of scheme" of Eisenbud Harris, after that I want to begin with a generalization of scheme that is algebraic spaces, I know only the book of Knutson "Algebraic Spaces", but, it can appear quite babyish, the character in which is written that book (that is the usual character of Springer's book) is very annoying to me. Other references?

Comment: Have a look at the relevant part of the [Stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/025R). Anyway, you may have more luck finding material on [algebraic stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(mathematics)#References), which generalise both schemes and algebraic spaces...

Comment: After EH I think you want to learn more about the basic properties of schemes (EH don't do much of the hard work, although the book is still hard, if that makes any sense) and the cohomology of schemes. Jumping to algebraic space seems like a strange choice. I agree that the Stacks project is today's reference for these things though.

Comment: I agree with Hoot that it seems weird going to algebraic spaces from Eisenbud-Harris. There is so much that should be learned before that. However, I want to say that I would also advice against learning these things from the stacks project. I only use it to read up on technicalities when I'm already at least a little bit familiar with the given topic. To answer your question though: I think Knutson's book is really good. And as far as I know it is the only book that focuses purely on algebraic spaces. Also it can be read as a textbook really.

Comment: Other than that, there are online lecture notes on descent theory by Angelo Vistoli, which are very nice and will prepare you for both algebraic spaces and stacks. But again. If you've really only read EH, what's the motivation to study these things?

Comment: Coming across this again, I want to note that there is a new book by Olsson called _Algebraic Spaces and Stacks_, available from the AMS. It looks very useful for beginners.